# excel active X buttons getting bigger every action

Tags: excel, vba, button, size, activex

This is a question with the same title as here:
[VBA Active-X buttons getting bigger with every action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682545/vba-active-x-buttons-getting-bigger-with-every-action)

I guess the problem is the same.
The question is nevertheless from 2014!!! and it does not really have an answer.

In my case the buttons were NOT created programatically, but just clicking in insert activeX control, button, and then click for writing the VBA behind.

In order to better illustrate the problem I made a video with my handy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBiu2FfRxQU

IN the video you can see how every time a button is clicked it gets bigger.

as note aside I have to say that this only happens when I connect remotely with my computer via a think client. Nevertheless both screens are the same (i.e. have the same resolution).

This is of course very annoying because it makes almost impossible to use home working since connecting to my excel at work makes all the buttons go crazy in size.

Comment: Steer clear from ActiveX controls. I've seen posts about this problem in 2011, and the issue may have been going on for longer. Regular Form controls are unaffected. There is *no* proper fix. In some cases setting *Optimize for compatibility* works, but often it does not

Comment: The way I handled this in the past is to create a seperate macro that you call at the end of the click_event to resize it to stored properties. Furthermore I agree with Tim Stack, this is a known issue.

Comment: @JvdV in my case that wasn't even a desired "solution", as the click event would open a UF and therefore the user still saw the button behaving erratically. Wish they'd fix it already

Comment: Thanks. I understand now why in the "data community" (python & co.) hey all want to be away from excel. Sometimes it looks to me that Microsoft really wants to let die the most used "database" of the world. Sorry for the "opinionated" comment.

Comment: @TimStack but with regular Form control you have to assign a macro, you can not simply click and go to VBA editor, right?

Comment: @Berlines I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @timstack: When adding an activeX control (in form of a button as it is the case here) after clicking design mode in the developer ribbon you jump directly into the code behind the button in the VBA editor. Adding a regular form control does not offer that possibility, as far as I see, so the way forward is creating a macro named for instance XY and then go to list of macros and associate that macro with the active Form, which seems to be a lot of trouble if you have tens and tens of buttons. Am I right?

Comment: Not much of an issue of you name your buttons and macros logically, but yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

As @TimStack and @jvdv has pointed out this is a known issue of Microsoft, i.e. a BUG, there since many years.
Hence there is no solution but workarounds.
So stay away from controlX if you don't want to get surprises.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue today itself. And found very strange solution to this problem.

**I just tried to resize the button where I was facing the issue and it was solved.**

Hope this works with you.